# Multithreading - missing a thread at times

Tags: php

I am using PHP5. The below code is not processing all the threads at times. I noticed that 900+ accounts got missed during the process. Can you please help to review and let me know if I am missing anything in the code.
NOTE: it is not happening all the time.

```
$numInputsPerTask=1000;
$inputGroups=array_chunk($accounts,$numInputsPerTask);
$tasks=[];

foreach ($inputGroups as $inputKey => $inputForTask)
{
    $pid = pcntl_fork();

    if ($pid === -1) {
        die('could not fork');
    } else if ($pid === 0) {
        echo $inputKey . "\r\n";
        exit();
    } else {
        // We are the parent.
        $tasks[] = $pid;
        echo "Parent Task" . "\r\n";
        echo "Creating task" . print_r($tasks) . "\r\n";
    }

}

while(count($tasks) > 0) {
    foreach ($tasks as $key => $pid) {
        // We are still the parent.
        $res = pcntl_waitpid($pid, $status, WNOHANG);
        if ($res == -1 || $res > 0)
            unset($tasks[$key]);
    }
}

echo "Done";
```

Comment: Warning: PHP 5 is not supported anymore. Upgrade to a supported version to continue receiving updates, security patches etc: https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: Can you see any related messages in the server logs? Your server resources might be at their limits. Also, absolutely update your PHP to a current version, people might attack your server because of the old version.

Comment: It's best to assume some tasks will fail.  Ideally you'd either have a durable queue scheme or service like Amazon SQS where tasks must signal successful completion, or you've have a checker step after you think processing is done to catch and retry failed cases.

Comment: If using a database, if completed tasks are marked so they no longer show up in your SELECT then you could also just re-run the SELECT and job set until no rows are returned.  In your example above the first  SELECT returns 2,000 (for example) then the second SELECT returns the 900 that were skipped.